# Как реализовать дорисовку линий?

Tags: javascript, html

Проект - Создаются кружки и их должны связывать линии, кружки можно двигать и линии тоже будут вместе с ними двигаться.
При создании 3+ кружков линия действует только на двух из них ( то есть соединяет только два кружка, вместо 3). Так вот, как это исправить? (если вы будете запускать html, то надо тыкнуть на все кружки, чтобы они работали)

```js
let circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
let elements = [];
let newCircleButton = document.querySelector(".new-circle");

const drawLine = (e, i) => {
  let line = document.querySelector("#line");
  let circlesNode = document.querySelector(".circles");
  for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
    let c_el = elements[j];
    if (j != i) {
      line.setAttribute("x1", c_el.x);
      line.setAttribute("y1", c_el.y);
      line.setAttribute("x2", e.pageX);
      line.setAttribute("y2", e.pageY);
      line.setAttribute("stroke", "#000000");
    }
  }
}

const onMouseDown = (e, el, i) => {
  const moveAt = (e) => {
    el.style.left = e.pageX - el.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
    el.style.top = e.pageY - el.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
    elements[i] = {
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY
    }
    drawLine(e, i);
  }

  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  moveAt(e);
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.style.zIndex = 1000;
  document.onmousemove = (e) => {
    moveAt(e);
  }
  el.onmouseup = () => {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    el.onmouseup = null;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
  circles[i].addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    onMouseDown(e, circles[i], i)
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <svg id="svg"><line id="line"/></svg>
</div>
```